# Offset Range copying

Tags: excel, range

Excel will receive data at A1 from a special link on a timed basis.  When the value = 1, I need data contained in `B1:F1` to be copied to `B10:F10`.  Next time interval, the value will be 2 and data at `B1:F1` needs to be copied to `B11:F11` and so on.

`IF Range("A1").Value = X then Range("B(x+10):F(x+10)") = Range("B1:F1").Value` is incorrect.  What is the correct syntax?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Range("A1").Value = x Then Range("B" & x + 10 & ":F" & x + 10) = Range("B1:F1").Value
```

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the time taken to address the question.